# PIE disabled. Absolute addressing when asm programming with gcc on mac OS X

Tags: macos, assembly, gcc, x86-64

I wrote the code below. I want to compile it using gcc on mac OS X,
but I get a message saying "PIE disabled. Absolute addressing" when I run gcc.

I googled it, but cannot find a solution.

Please advise.

hello.s file:

```
.data
hello: .string "Hello World!\n"

.text
.globl _main

_main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    movabs $hello, %rdi
    call _printf
    leave
    ret
```

The error:

```
ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in
code signed PIE, but used in _main from /var/folders/xs/4z9kr_n93111fhv9_j1dd9gw0000gn/T/ex2_64-369300.o. 
To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
```

Comment: You must use relative addressing. Instead of `movabs` do `lea hello(%rip), %rdi`. Also, you might have to zero `AL` because `printf` is vararg.

Comment: Thanks to your advise I complile it completely.

Comment: I don't understand this error completely. In case 32 bit, What do I use instead of 'push $hello'?

Comment: 32 bit is usually not `PIC` except for libraries. You need to use clever trick to get the actual load address of a known reference point and then address relative to that point. This is typically done by fetching the return address from the stack after a `CALL` instruction. For libraries, you get special support by the assembler for handling stuff like `GOT` and `PLT`.

Comment: based on the error message where it says "to fix this warning..." you might try, as I did, `clang -o hello hello.s -Wl,-no_pie` to get what you wrote to assemble and link.  Alternatively, follow the suggestion from @Jester and use `lea`.  @Jester is also correct about `al`.  See section 3.5.7 of the ABI docs.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there are a couple solutions:

1. Link with -Wl,-no_pie:

```
clang -o hello hello.s -Wl,-no_pie
```

2. Don't use absolute addressing.

```
.data
hello: .string "Hello World!\n"

.text
.globl _main

_main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    lea hello(%rip), %rdi
    mov $0, %rax
    call _printf
    leave
    ret
```

Then you can compile and run:

```
host % clang -o hello hello.s            
host % ./hello 
Hello World!
```

The bit about zeroing out al is mentioned in section 3.5.7 of System V Application Binary Interface. Here's the relevant excerpt:

> When a function taking variable-arguments is called, %al must be set
> to the total num- ber of floating point parameters passed to the
> function in vector registers.

In your case this is zero.  You are passing in zero floating point parameters.

Comment: The efficient way to zero AL is `xor %eax,%eax`.  `mov $0, %eax` is less efficient but perhaps more obvious; `mov $0, %rax` is even less efficient than that (eve more code size), and seems like a weird choice when we know that only `mov $0, %al` would be sufficient for correctness.  But yeah, for the main question, seems like MacOS doesn't do runtime fixups of 64-bit absolute addresses in PIE executables, or at least not in the `.text` section.